# Reading words from an input file and grepping the lines containing the words from another file

Tags: linux, shell, scripting

I have a file containing list of 4000 words (`A.txt`). Now I want to grep lines from another file (`sentence_per_line.txt`) containing those 4000 words mentioned in the file `A.txt`.

The shell script I wrote for the above problem is

```
#!/bin/bash
file="A.txt"
while IFS= read -r line
do
        # display $line or do somthing with $line
        printf '%s\n' "$line"
        grep $line sentence_per_line.txt >> output.txt

        # tried printing the grep command to check its working or not 
        result=$(grep "$line" sentence_per_line.txt >> output.txt)
        echo "$result"

done <"$file"
```

And `A.txt` looks like this

```
applicable
available
White
Black
..
```

The code is neither working nor does it shows any error.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Grep has this built in:

```
grep -f A.txt sentence_per_line.txt > output.txt
```

Remarks to your code:

- Looping over a file to execute grep/sed/awk on each line is typically an antipattern, see [this Q&A](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/169716/why-is-using-a-shell-loop-to-process-text-considered-bad-practice).
- If your `$line` parameter contains more than one word, you have to quote it (doesn't hurt anyway), or grep tries to look for the first word in a file named after the second word:

  ```
  grep "$line" sentence_per_line.txt >> output.txt
  ```
- If you write output in a loop, don't redirect within the loop, do it outside:

  ```
  while read -r line; do
      grep "$line" sentence_per_line.txt
  done < "$file" > output.txt
  ```

  but remember, it's usually not a good idea in the first place.
- If you'd like to write to a file and at the same time see what you're writing, you can use `tee`:

  ```
  grep "$line" sentence_per_line.txt | tee output.txt
  ```

  writes to `output.txt` *and* stdout.
- If `A.txt` contains words which you want to match only if the complete word matches, i.e., `pattern` should not match `longerpattern`, you can use `grep -wf` – the `-w` matches only complete words.
- If the words in `A.txt` aren't regular expressions, but fixed strings, you can use `grep -fF` – the `-F` option looks for fixed strings and is faster. These two can be combined: `grep -WfF`

Comment: "grep -f A.txt sentence_per_line.txt > output.txt" Takes only a last word from the file and grep the sentences containing the last word

Comment: Do you have Windows line endings? What does `cat -A A.txt` show? If there is `^M` at line endings, those are carriage returns. Does it work after `dos2unix A.txt`?

Comment: And what to do if I want to print the words which are matched in sentence_per_line.txt in a separate output file? Just to know what are the words matched in sentence_per_line.txt

Comment: @Doej There is the `-o` option for grep, which returns only what it matches instead of whole lines.

Comment: Can it be used in the same way "grep -o A.txt sentence_per_line.txt >op.txt"? doesn't show any output

Comment: @Doej You still need `-f` to indicate that the next argument is a file and not a pattern: `grep -of A.txt sentence_per_line.txt > op.txt`